# Is there any difference between "image generation" and "image synthesis"?

Tags: comparison, terminology, image-generation

Generative Adversarial networks (aka GANs) are used for image generation. The phrase [image synthesis](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&q=image%20synthesis) is also used in literature.

I know that the phrase **image generation** stands for

> An act of generating an image

The [formal definition](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/image-synthesis) for **image synthesis** is given by

> Image synthesis is the process of artificially generating images that
> **contain some particular desired content**.

The only difference I can notice is that image synthesis is a focused image generation. The focus is on the parts of the image generated.

But, I have an issue with the word *synthesis*. The word "synthesis" has the [following meanings](https://www.lexico.com/definition/synthesis)

1. The *combination of components or elements* to form a connected whole. Often contrasted with analysis
2. The production of chemical *compounds* by reaction from simpler materials.
3. (in Hegelian philosophy) the final stage in the process of dialectical reasoning, in which a new idea resolves the conflict between thesis and antithesis.

It gives me a sense that I need to use the phrase "image synthesis" if I am generating an image by **combining** some simpler elements, which is not exactly the same as the focused sense given in the formal definition of image synthesis.

Why does the word "synthesis" is used in the phrase "image synthesis"? Are we synthesizing/combining anything that does not happen in other variants of image generation?